# What information does Fuseki DB folder contain

Tags: jena, fuseki

Curious to know what kind of data fuseki DB folder contains (`apache-jena-fuseki-2.4.0/DB/`). Iam using apache jena fuski 2.4.0 version. Even if I try upload and drop of graphs to fuseki datasets or dataset deletion or normal graph updates, no files in DB get changed and its size remain constant sometimes. Could anyone please help me understand about the data gets stored in the DB folder?

Comment: Apache Jena Fuseki 2.4.0 is old (2016-05). The current version is 4.1.0 (June 2021).

Comment: To get a directory `/DB/` the server was probably started at some point with command line arguments for a TDB database in `/DB/` - what configuration are you using? Otherwise it uses the `run/` area which is managed through the UI.. (caveat: 2.4.0 was a long time ago and this is what the current version does).

Comment: @AndyS
```# Licensed under the terms of http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

## Fuseki Server configuration file.

@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ; ```
This is the content in config.ttl file in the directory

Comment: Running that and creating a database called "DB" will create "run/databases/DB"; `run` is the area used to store the server configuration. List the file in the directory - it is probably a database (TDB1 or TDB2).

Comment: Thanks @AndyS, for the clarification

Comment: Using a drop graph command to delete graphs from fuseki, not reducing the size of ```/run/databases```. Tried dropping several graphs from fuseki, but it didn't make any impact in the folders in the specified path. Does it mean, drop graph command will not delete the contents from DB? If so, is there any way to delete the dependant data for the deleted graphs?

Comment: It does delete the graph. It will not reduce the size of a TDB2 database until a compact is run. https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb2/tdb2_admin.html. For TDB1, a backup-restore is needed to free up all of the space. (information relates to current Jena version which is 4.1.0)

Comment: One query regarding backup-restore process; When drop graph query is used to delete a graph stored in a dataset, not any more that graph will be visible through UI, but the dependant data doesn't get deleted from the fuseki folder. Will this be resolved when we use the backup-restore process? Will this clean up all the data related to the dropped graphs from a dataset?

Comment: backup-restore will rebuild a database with only the visible data in it. TDB2 has the "compact" operation for this which works on a live, running system.